# PHP, Sorting Articles

Tags: php, sql, sorting

I have a dynamically generated site,
The pages (like Home, Contact...) have articles.
I store everything in SQL.
The question is: 
How Should I sort the articles with an admin page?
example:
Homepage:
It has 3 article: News, Zzz, Test
In SQL the articles have "contentOrder", News -> 1, Zzz ->2, Test->3,
If in the admin page, the user want the Zzz article to be the 1st, I do smthng like this:

```
        mysql_query('UPDATE pagescontent SET contentOrder=0 WHERE contentOrder='.$aktOrder);
        mysql_query("UPDATE pagescontent SET contentOrder=$aktOrder WHERE contentOrder=$aktOrderUp");
        mysql_query("UPDATE pagescontent SET contentOrder=$aktOrderUp WHERE contentOrder=0");
```

I simply swap the 2 articles "contentOrder". But the problem is, the only way i can do this when the contentOrder is the primary key, coz i should move the whole row to do somthng, if it isnt a primary key, only the contentOrder gonna be changed.

I dont rly know how should i do this.(Should I make another table for the ContentOrder ?)

Sry for my bad english. :/

Comment: I'm having a little difficulty understanding the 2nd part of your question. But if you are trying to change the order of sections inside your admin page, why not spit out the contentOrder Id (Primary Key) into the HTML. Then when you click the button to move content up or down, pass that Id back to your PHP. So your PHP can do a query like `UPDATE pagecontent SET contentOrder=contentOrder+1 WHERE contentOrder_Id=$contentOrderId`. Note that it can be contentOrder+1 or contentOrder-1 depending on if you are pushing it up or down. Is that what you are looking for ? If not please clarify

Comment: My problem is the sql part, coz my pagescontent looks like this:
id, pagesConnection(thats define what page is the article connected), contentOrder ( the order), text (the article's text)
So when I change the Order, i only changed a number, what is totally useless

Comment: If your Problem is how to retrieve the data on correct order, use the ORDER BY clause (select * from YOURTABLE order by contentOrder) - this may be what you want. You also can specify if you want to the data ordered ascending/descending

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly, but:
If you define the order of your data using the contentOrder column (which you update, to reflect this), you can simple select them using an "Order by" clause. You do not need the contentOrder column to be a Primary key (but you could include it in an index, so the data is already sorted correctly - it depends on your usage/data).

to change sorting you could generate a "bulk" update, 
e.g. 
if you want to move an item from contentOrder 3 to be the first one:

```
update pagescontent set contentOrder = contentOrder - 1 where contentOrder > 3 and contentOrder <= $newPosition
```

/// where 3 is the contentOrder of the item you wnat to move up and $newPosition is the new contentOrder
followed by an update of the existingRow you jsut moved,:

```
update pagescontent set contentOrder = $newPosition where id = $idOfRecordToMoveUp
```

similar to this you can perform operations for other sort operations.

You can select the Top 'x' articles and order them by the contentOrder column (depending on your Database system you can do this with TOP/Limit clause).
E.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM pagescontent ORDER BY contentOrder
```

You also can order the data ascending/descending, usually by adding ASC or DESC to the ORDER BY clause (not sure if this works for your database system).
I also would recommend to use Parameters for your queries, to avoid SQL Injection, and other possible problems.

Comment: Its an admin page, Should I care about sql injection? If smbdy can see the inputs its already late.

Comment: I somebody gets access to your admin page, he could steal/delete/whatever your or your customers data etc. 
Or to sum up: I would care.

Comment: But if smbdy gets access, he can do the same with the admin functions. He can delete everything from a graphical interface, he dont need sql injection.

Answer (score 1):

Consider what happens if you try to make the 8th article the first. The article which is currently first should become the second, the second become third and so on and so forth. So rather than switching the two contentOrder values, you actually need to update the rest of them to match.

Given that consideration, my solution would be to query for all the articles, sort them and then update all the rows in the database with the new order. If you can do that in a stored procedure, or otherwise without making all those queries in PHP, that might be preferable.

Hopefully, I can explain that better with this:

You have your starting content order (in the format [article ID, content order]):

```
[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4]
```

You now want to make your article ID 4 the first article, so your list would become

```
[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 1]
```

Comment: I have up and down links, so when you want to move the 8th article, you have to click the UP image/link, then the 8th artice moves up, and become the 7th. Thats why i would like to swap them.

Comment: Aha, then my answer is mostly useless!

Comment: Sorry, I should have said that earlier. :(